# How to show a notification if a startup application (or process) failed to start automatically

Tags: scripts, notification, autostart, logging

I added a script to autostart (using **Default applications for LXSession**). Later, I moved the folder containing the script.

As result, the autostart command was silently failing.

How can I enable warning messages about failed autostart commands?

Answer (score 7):

The solution below is not specifically for Lubuntu, only the way to *set* an application to autostart from GUI is a bit different, since `Lubuntu` does not have the **Startup Applications** application, like Ubuntu.

#### Check if a script has started within a certain time limit from login

With the script below, you can check if a script started successfully, within a certain time limit from login. If the startup(s) was *unsuccessful*, a message will appear, mentioning which of the scripts did not start successfully. You can use it to check on multiple scripts or processes in one step.

[image]

After the time limit has passed and sent its message, the script terminates

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `proc_check.py` in a *permanent* :) location.
2. In the head of the script, set the list of processes (script names) to keep an eye on, and set the time limit.
3. Make sure the processes (to check) are not running, and test-run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/proc_check.py
   ```

   It should send a warning after the time limit has passed.
4. If all works fine, add the command below to your Startup Applications:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/proc_check.py
   ```

*Note:*

If you have `notify-send` available (`sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`), you can also uncomment the before-last line, to get a confirmation if all went well:

[image]

The advantage of that is that you will *either* get a notification that all went well, or a warning, mentioning which of the processes did not start up successfully. 
You will notice then if you accidentally moved *this* script. :)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import time

#--- set the processes (script names) to check below
procs = ["pscript_2.py", "monkey.py"]
#--- set the time limit below (seconds)
wait = 30
#---

# define the user to fetch the current user's process list
user = getpass.getuser()
# create an (empty) list of succesful process startups
succeeded = []

def get():
    return subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-u", user, "ww"]).decode("utf-8")

t = 1
while t < wait:
    # add succesful processes to the "succeeded" list
    for p in [proc for proc in procs if proc in get()]:
        succeeded.append(p)
    time.sleep(1)
    t = t+1

# list the failures
fails = [p for p in procs if not succeeded.count(p) > 2]
# if there are any, send a message
if len(fails) > 0:
    subprocess.Popen(["zenity", "--info", "--text", "failed to run: "+(", ").join(fails)])
# if all was successfull, send a message; n.b. comment out the line if notify-send is not available
else:
    # subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "All processes started succesfully"])
    pass
```

Comment: And if he again removed by mistake? ;)

Comment: Exactly, that's why I mentioned "save it as proc_check.py in a *permanent :)* location". But true of course :)

Comment: @A.B. I think I cought that one (see the "note") :)

Answer (score 4):

It is assumed that your startup programs are in `/home/<your_username>/.config/autostart/`.

And than something like this in your crontab:

```
awk -F'[= ]' '/^Exec/{print $2}' /home/<your_username>/.config/autostart/*.desktop | while IFS= read -r target; do [ ! -x "${target/\~/$HOME}" ] &&  ! type "${target/\~/$HOME}" &> /dev/null  && echo "Not executable: $target" | mail -s "Missing commands" <your_username>; done
```

Open your crontab with:

```
crontab -e
```

and add this line:

```
* */2 * * *       awk -F'[= ]' '/^Exec/{print $2}' /home/<your_username>/.config/autostart/*.desktop | while IFS= read -r target; do [ ! -x "$target" ] &&  ! type "$target" &> /dev/null  && echo "Not executable: $target" | mail -s "Missing commands" <your_username>; done
```

This will check your files in `.config/autostart/` every two hours and send a mail, if there is a problem.

Thanks [@terdon](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47392/terdon)

Comment: It will catch only this type of error (moving file directly mentioned in autostart), it will not catch other causes of failing autostart command. But it a bit of my fault to not mention clearly enough that I want to detect any kind of failure of autostart programs.